# Dropdown button with XPages do not look like on the Bootstrap site

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, xpages-extlib

I am using the bootstrap theme from extension library and try to make the bootstrap dropdown button look like the one on the bootstrap site.

This is what the dropdown looks like on the bootstrap site

[image]

This is what the dropdown look like when using the bootstrap theme in the extlib demo database. I have also tried to use the same sample code from the bootstrap site but the button is still not "flat"

[image]

How can I make my dropdown button to have the same "flat" style as in the bootstrap site and why do the bootstrap theme in extlib not making it flat?

Comment: When you use the developer tools in your browser, you can see what are the class/css differences. Then you can edit them until they look the same directly in the browser. Once satisfied create your theme that extends the bootstrap theme and flatten them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two boostrap themes that come with the extlib, one is Bootstrap3.2.0 which is the 3d version and **Boostrap3.2.0_flat** which is the one you need to show the flat buttons.

Answer (score 2):

The Bootstrap implementation in Extlib covers two themes: normal (Bootstrap3.2.0) and flat (Bootstrap3.2.0_flat). Just change the theme name in XSP props / in your theme in the extends attribute.